# Check if duplicate key/value across two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-2.0

**Scenario:**

Inputs: Arrays of Designation & Scale of teachers

```
A1:
[designation] => Array
    (
        [0] => 24
        [1] => 25
        [2] => 26
        [3] => 27
        [4] => 24
        [5] => 25
    )

[grade_scale] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 10
    )
```

Now, there is a same designation being repeated twice in A1 array, that's fine because same designation with different grades in A2 can exist.

However, if there are 2 occurrences of same designation then their grades should be different.

In above scenario, Designation 24 and 25 are duplicates.

- Designation 25 is OK because of different grades
- Designation 24 is not OK because of same grades i.e 1 and 1 at exactly same indexes.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
$counts = array_count_values($a1);


$filtered = array_filter($a1, function ($value) use ($counts) {
    return $counts[$value] > 1;
});
```

`$filtered` array gives me index numbers of duplicates.

```
$filtered
(
    [0] => 24
    [1] => 25
    [4] => 24
    [5] => 25
)
```

I want to check whether the values at same indexes in A2 array are duplicate too. In this scenario, designation 24 is having same grades in A2 at same indexes.

Comment: var_dump(array_intersect_key($array1, $array2));

Comment: @mwweb Trying to check if designations are same and grades for those same designations are also same.

Comment: so you have 1 array not 2

Comment: @mwweb In other words, High School Teacher with Grade 1 "OK".
High School Teacher with Grade 1 again not "OK" because it has already been mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to check whether the values at same indexes in A2 array are duplicate
>   too

The solution using `array_filter`, `array_count_values`, `array_intersect_key`, `array_flip` and `array_unique` functions:

```
$a1 = [0 => 24, 1 => 25, 2 => 26, 3 => 27, 4 => 24, 5 => 25];
$a2 = [0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 4, 4 => 1, 5 => 10];

// getting all duplicate designation values from $a1 array
$counts = array_filter(array_count_values($a1), function($v){ return $v > 1; });
$dup_designations = [];

// iterating through all duplicate 'designation' items from $a1  array
foreach ($counts as $k => $v) {
    // obtaining respective items from $a2 array by key intersection 
    // with  current designation items sequence  
    $grades = array_intersect_key($a2, array_flip(array_keys($a1, $k)));

    // check if found duplicates within $a2 array have the same value
    if (count(array_unique($grades)) != count($grades)) {
        $dup_designations[] = $k;
    }
}

print_r($dup_designations);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 24
)
```

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you and if possible, could you please elaborate your solution?

Comment: @Pallew, you're welcome. I've added some explanation via comments